# Julia, ploting histogram or whatever from a serie of files in a loop (list)

Tags: bash, plot, histogram, julia

Time ago, I did move some files from a directory and copied to a new one, 
while copying I did rename each one. For doing so , I used bash.
Something like this

```
for i in 8 12 16 20 ; do;
   for j in 0.00 0.01 ; do ;    
    cp  tera.dat new/tera$i$j.dat 
...
```

Into each tera$i$j.dat, there is numeric data in 2 columns. 
I would like to plot the data as a histogram, and save each image (if possible in a loop) for each file tera$i$j.dat . But unfortunately, I do not have much idea how to do this.
I managed to load the data in several tables using `de = readtable.(filter(r"tera", readdir()),separator =' ', header= false,;`. 
But I can not create a plot for each data :( 
So far I managed to read the file, and create a histogram plot for **1** file per time, how do I do it in a loop ?  This is the code I am using.

```
using Plots StatPlots,  Distributions, DataFrames, PlotlyJS, LaTeXStrings;
theme(:sand);
chp = pwd(); 
pe = readtable("tera120.00.dat",separator =' ', header= false)
gr()
histogram(pe[2], nbins=1000)
...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow! In order to get a good answer for your question you should try and limit the code to a minimal reproducible example as well as providing the error messages you are getting. As it stands it is hard to know exactly what you are asking and thus hard to help :) perhaps this might help too https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlexanderMorley I did follow your advise. Let´s see .

Comment: If my answer below resolved the problem, could you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but it should be something like this:

```
using StatPlots, DataFrames
theme(:sand)
gr()
for i in [8, 12, 16, 20], j in [0, 0.01]
    fn = @sprintf "tera%02d.%02d" i j
    pe = readtable(fn*".dat", separator =' ', header = false)
    p = histogram(pe[2], bins = 1000);
    savefig(p, fn*".png")
end
```

Note that when you plot with StatPlots, you don't need `using Plots` or `using PlotlyJS`, I also don't see why you need `Distributions` or `LaTeXStrings`.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Julia reads the 1st file as tera80.0.dat instead of tera80.00.dat. About `StatPlots`  is did not know, thanks :) . Regarding `Distributions`, well it is form a old script , and `LaTeXStrings`  is for the legend and title.

Comment: That's not an issue with my solution. My post answered your question. It is an issue with your file naming scheme.

Comment: But if you do need to follow that format for some reason you can use @sprintf as an alternative to string interpolation: `fn = @sprintf "tera%02d.%02d" i j`. I've updated the answer to show that.

Comment: Dear Michael, a partial solution was not a solution. But the answer that you provided helped  get very  close. I did changed `0.00` by `"0.00"` , and so on with all the values that finished in `00`, for instance `1.00 , 2.00 `.

Comment: I think this "0.00"  would better that using `@sprintf`, cause now instead of having  tera80.00.dat I do have  tera08.00.dat ... But anyway, that a lot for the answer.  :)

Comment: What I mean is, there is no way to see from your question that you have a file labeled "tera80.00.dat" - I can only answer the question you actually pose :-)

Comment: From the way your question is phrased now, it looks as if you always add zero regardless of the number. If that for some reason is true you can just `fn = "tera$(i)0.$(j)"`